# asp.net core / EF core multiple async requests throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Whenever i do multiple requests to the same controller only first request returns data, rest of requests throw error- Object not set to an instance of an object.

```
    public async Task<List<BusinessUnit>> GetBusinessUnits(ContextUser user)
    {
        return await db.BusinessUnits.Where(x => x.Company.Id == user.SelectedCompany).Include(x => x.Company).ToListAsync();
    }
```

However if i remove await operator it works fine.

```
return db.BusinessUnits.Where(x => x.Company.Id == user.SelectedCompany).Include(x => x.Company).ToList();
```

Startup.cs

```
  services.AddDbContext<RepoDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

 services.AddTransient<IBusinessUnit, BusinessUnitRepository>();
```

Does EF share the same dbContext in thoes requests?

What could cause this behavior?

EDIT:
This is my dbContext class

```
 public class RepoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public RepoDbContext(DbContextOptions<RepoDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

And dbcontext in repository being injected by DI

```
 RepoDbContext db;

    public BusinessUnitRepository(RepoDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class BusinessUnitAPIController : BaseController
{
    IBusinessUnit BusinessUnits;
    readonly new ContextUser User;

    public BusinessUnitAPIController(UserContextResolve userContextResolver, IBusinessUnit _BusinessUnits)
    {
        User = userContextResolver.GetUserContext;
        BusinessUnits = _BusinessUnits;
    }

    public async Task<List<BusinessUnit>> GetBusinessUnits()
    {
            var result = await BusinessUnits.GetBusinessUnits(User);
            return result;
    }

}
```

IBusinessUnit:

```
  public interface IBusinessUnit
{
    Task<List<BusinessUnit>> GetBusinessUnits(ContextUser user);
}
```

Comment: What is `db`? Where is it allocated/passed to the controller?

Comment: Is `ContextUser` null? Maybe because the method execution resumes on a different context. Show the full stack trace along with details relevant to `ContextUser`.

Comment: ContextUser Comes from DI and it's not null.

Comment: Can you brief what exactly is the error ?

Comment: Which scope does your dependency injected context classes have?

Comment: We miss the most cruical information... what your DI registrations for `BusinessUnitRepository`/`IBusinessUnit` and possibly `UserContextResolve`

Comment: It also throws error without `UserContextResolve `. Added Interface and DI from startup.

Comment: `Database.EnsureCreated()` in your constructor doesn't look right and it wouldn't surprise me if this is causing your problem.  You should only perform this once in `Startup.cs`.